# Would CLR migration to the native c++ project be a cause of slowness?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, clr

I have a C++ native project and enabled CLR then release mode executable had been very slow.
Why does it occur?

Comment: The title and body seem to be reversed. Did you change from native **to**  CLR/.Net or from CLR **to** native? There are rare cases where the CLR can be faster, but as a rule native is faster.

Comment: Native code is almost always faster but usually not so much. What is your code doing? Is it CPU intensive? Is it allocating memory very often? Doing I/O?

Comment: I only parsing text data that was retrieved from web page. only using standard library functions.

Comment: What was the command argument you used to enable the CLR? If some methods are converted to managed and others are not, then you could end up with superfluous managed->unmanaged transitions (with their accompanying security checks).